# Is it possible to make hyperlinks inside nodes in Cytoscape.js?

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js, cytoscape

I want users to be able to click on some text inside the node and do some action, like show some dialog or open some other window. Is this possible?

In the documentation there is something like :

> **text-events** : Whether events should occur on an element if the label receives an event; may be yes or no. You may want a style applied to the text on :active so you know the text is activatable.

it seems like the thing but there is no example how to use it on the label level..

EDIT: example
[on the diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gGhuw.png)

how I imagine it could be in the code:

```
  label_element.on('tap', function(event){
     // cyTarget holds a reference to the label
     var evtTarget = event.cyTarget;
     //...
  });
```

or

```
  cy.on('tap', function(event){
     var evtTarget = event.cyTarget;
     //evtTarget holds element but I can somehow get the text which got tap event??
  });
```

Comment: Please post some code to illustrate it.

Comment: hi @alvaro.scalasoft , thanks for the answer, please have a look a the edits above

Comment: All right! This code works for you?

Comment: no, this is just mocked up code snippets with my vision on how it could work. So far I didnt manage to get it working, mostly because there is no such object like label_element... I think I'll try and place context.fillText() caption on top of the canvas. It seems to work but once I zoom in/out it disappears..

Comment: You can try manipulate it using something like cy.$('selector')

Comment: yes, but cy.$('selector') will select only elements like nodes or edges, right? There is no way, as far as I know, to select the specific label or text inside the node...

Answer (score 0):

According Cytoscape.js documentation, you may try do this using

> cy.on('tap')

, like this:
Examples

Bind to events that bubble up from elements matching the specified node selector:

```
    cy.on('tap', 'node', { foo: 'bar' }, function(evt){
      console.log( evt.data.foo ); // 'bar'

      var node = evt.cyTarget;
      console.log( 'tapped ' + node.id() );
    });
```

Bind to all tap events that the core receives:

```
    cy.on('tap', function(event){
      // cyTarget holds a reference to the originator
      // of the event (core or element)
      var evtTarget = event.cyTarget;

      if( evtTarget === cy ){
          console.log('tap on background');
      } else {
        console.log('tap on some element');
      }
    });
```

At http://js.cytoscape.org/#cy.on

Answer (score 0):

If `text-events: yes`, tapping a node's label will trigger `tap` on the node.

If you want to have arbitrary UIs on top of nodes that can be independently interacted with, then you should create a separate layer in the DOM.

Rationale : The labels are relatively simple in Cytoscape.js, because supporting complex ones would be on the same order of complexity as the DOM.  In that case, it's better to use the DOM as a layer on top of the graph rather than to reimplement it in Cytoscape.js.

Comment: thanks @maxkfranz , it seems rational to me. How do you create such DOM layer on top of canvas? Can you give some basic example? Also, how to make it interact with changes on underlying canvas e.g. when zooming the diagram I'd expect the DOM based labels to zoom also..

Comment: You'll have to create a div aligned on top and sync state changes with the graph.

Comment: @maxkfranz My colleague and I are looking for a direct answer to this question.  Could you possibly create a small example for us?  Please and thanks